# LG WebOS - Loader comes before splash

Tags: splash-screen, loader, webos, lg

We are observing loader for few seconds before our splash video plays on LG Web OS application.

How do we avoid loader, and start splash directly on application launch ?

Any help would be really appreciated.. !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding your custom loading image beside your splash screen logic in the code itself. Add `splashBackground` to your appinfo.json file with a relative path.

Check the resources provided by LG for developers.
https://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/references/appinfo-json#splashbackground